# Macro is clearing all cells instead of those that equal 0 after a Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs and formats a weekly report of aging invoices. It runs a `Vlookup` against the previous week's file to return the updates input by the Buyers. I have an IFERROR put in so that I don't get `#N/A` returned. We also have some code written that was intended to change any cells equal to "0," but it's not working.

Instead of changing just the cells equal to 0 to blank, it's clearing ALL cell values, including the updates that were input by the Vlookup. I am nowhere near a code expert, and the person who was helping me with this has taken a new role and is quite busy. I managed to fix a couple other issues with the code, but this has me stumped.

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:V" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0"
Range("I2", "I" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

Set myrange = Selection
If myrange Is Nothing Then

Else
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.FillDown
    Selection.AutoFilter
End If
```

Comment: Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Avoid any `Selection`, `Select` and `Activate` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with PEH's comment about avoiding select statements and the like and further I would add its best to avoid things like Activesheet - instead always specify what sheet you're referring to.

in any case, there are many way to do what you're looking for. One way would be to use the [Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) of the Range class, this works much like the find and replace dialogue you get when you press Ctrl+F.

```
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' replace formulas with their result
Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole ' replace "0" with an empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it will clear the values of all cells with `0` in column "I". Explanations inside the code's comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearZerosOnly()

Dim Rng As Range, myRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change "sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter

    Set Rng = .Range("A1:V" & LastRow)
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="0" ' set the Auto-Filter criteria 

    ' set the Visible range and column I (from row 2, without header)
    Set myRange = Application.Intersect(Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Range("I2:I" & LastRow))
End With

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then myRange.ClearContents

End Sub
```